# Virtual hosts instead of separate IPs?

Tags: virtualization, ip, host

I've been wondering if it's possible to host multiple applications using a single port on one IP address. I'm meaning a similar method to Apache Virtual Hosts where you can assign domains/subdomains to  specific directories, though I'd like to do this where I can host several applications using one port but have a subdomain which determines which application you are connecting to.

An example of how this would work in my head is:

```
app_server.exe (Instance 1): 111.111.111.111:9999
app_server.exe (Instance 2): 111.111.111.111:9999
```

Then if I connect to `app1.example.com` it connects to `Instance 1`, whereas `app2.example.com` would connect to `Instance 2`.

I have no idea whether this is actually possible or not, but I have look and I have no clue as to what it would even be called, so this is my best bet.

Comment: Only if the protocol supports it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate upon that @MichaelHampton?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done, as long as the application-level protocol in use knows which name was connected to.  HTTP knows this, because of the `Host:` header.  TLS knows this (now), because of the "Server Name Indication" extension.  I believe FTP can know this, based on some protocol extension, but if you're still using FTP, you are doomed.

If the protocol *doesn't* have the ability to indicate which name was used, then you can't do this, because all the server knows when a connection is made is the source and destination IP/port are involved.  Everything else needs to passed at a higher level.

One point as to your proposed implementation: you'll need to have a *single* service listening on the port which receives the connections, parses the incoming data sufficiently to be able to determine which name was requested, and then (and *only* then) can it route the request to different instances of the application for processing.  If those instances are separate processes, then some means of communicating the request to the backend which will handle it (such as proxying, or, if you're dealing with a *really* good protocol design, socket handoff), but if you implement the various handlers in the same process (say, with configuration or dynamically loadable modules) then you can just create a data structure with the request in it and pass it off to whatever wants to deal with it.

Comment: Okay, so if I am running several game servers this may work, or not? Where would I begin/what software is there that I can experiment with?

Comment: It almost certainly won't work; game server protocols are notoriously hideous.  I don't know what to suggest for "experimentation", because I don't know what you want to experiment with.

Comment: Well essentially, I would like to run multiple game servers that "ignore" the fact that there is any other game servers running on that port. From then on, one you connect to app1.example.com it will point towards that file ("app_server.exe"), I'm not really entirely sure on how else to describe it. :p

Comment: Well essentially, the protocol needs to support that.

Comment: Right, so can this connection management be done with a high level language like PHP or do I need to get deeper than that?

Comment: With the information given so far, it's probably not possible.

Comment: Well can I use a PHP daemon to in the simplest example possible; detect the domain used, then route the connection to the place it needs to go? So let's imagine 'app.exe' default port is   `app.server.com:3000`  Is "forwarded" or "translated" (not sure on the correct word to use there) seamlessly to:     `app.exe` listening on port 3001  Then, `app1.server.com:3000` would forward to `app.exe` listening on port 3002, Almost like an alias?

Comment: Not unless the protocol involved allows it.